# C# Use OpenCV ROI with thread

Tags: c#, opencv

I would like to merge multiple small images to create a big image. As I have a lot of small image I would like to use threads.

OpenCV allows to select an ROI, so I would like to copy a small image in a predefined ROI.
The problem is that by using threads, the ROI changes before having had time to copy the small image into the large one.

To illustrate this problem I have the following code:

```
private void Test()
{
        int size = 256;
        //Create RGB Image
        Image<Bgr, byte> R = new Image<Bgr, byte>(size, size, new Bgr(Color.Red));
        Image<Bgr, byte> G = new Image<Bgr, byte>(size, size, new Bgr(Color.Green));
        Image<Bgr, byte> B = new Image<Bgr, byte>(size, size, new Bgr(Color.Blue));
        Image<Bgr, byte>[] imageArray = new Image<Bgr, byte>[3] { R, G, B};

        Image<Bgr, byte> merger = new Image<Bgr, byte>(size * 3, size, new Bgr(Color.Black));

        // Create final image with thread
        Parallel.For(0, imageArray.Length, i =>
        {
            merger.ROI = new Rectangle(i * 256, 0, size, size);
            imageArray[i].CopyTo(merger);
        });

        merger.ROI = Rectangle.Empty;
        
        //Show the image
        Utils.ShowImage(merger);

        //Free
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            imageArray[i].Dispose();
        merger.Dispose();
}
```

I create 3 small images, one red, one green, one blue. I merge these 3 images into one to create this result:

[image]

But with threads I have the following result:

[image]

Is there a way to select multiple ROIs and keep the benefit of the threads?

Comment: "the ROI changes before having had time to copy" -- yes, that's bound to happen if you have multiple threads change the same thing (the ROI) without any synchronization. | Anyway, what's wrong with `hconcat`?

Comment: And assuming you're using EmguCV, then `Image` should have method `GetSubRect`, which appears to be equivalent to `cv::Mat::operator()`. As long as the sub-images created do not overlap, you can use the concurrently without problems (unlike the ROI feature).